# Invoke method and use args[0] as an argument in that method

Tags: java, args

```
public class a2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isHappy(args[0]);
    }

    public static boolean isHappy(){
        int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if(i == 132){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a question because I am new at JAVA, how can I invoke method isHappy from main method and use args[0] as an argument in method isHappy? This is my code. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, arg[] is typically known as command line argument

Comment: Your `isHappy` method does not define any parameters.

Comment: Your `isHappy` method does not return a value unless `i == 132`

Comment: What should I define as parameters in method isHappy in my case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to learn Java naming convention, in java class name first Letter should be capital.

```
public class A2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        isHappy(args[0]);

    }

    //Function must take arugment
    public static boolean isHappy(String str) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        if (i == 132) {
            return false;
        }
        return true; //missing return type
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isHappy()
```

needs to be

```
public static boolean isHappy(String[] param)
```

where param can be nearly whatever name you want. *There are some restrictions*

Otherwise, your method can't accept parameters and the compiler should give you an error.

**Edit:**

If you want to transfer only a `String`, like `args[0]` to `isHappy`, then use `public static boolean isHappy(String param)`

Comment: Maybe.  It's kind of unclear to me whether the OP is going for `String[] param` or `String param`

Comment: @MFisherKDX Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value args[0] as a parameter for the isHappy function,
Also this code is not having a return statement outside the if
So adding else with return as true;

```
public class a2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   isHappy(args[0]);
}
public static boolean isHappy(String argValue){
  int i = Integer.parseInt(argValue);
  if(i == 132){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

}